# Redirecionar valor da função time para arquivo

Tags: bash

Estou tentando usar a função time no terminal. 
Quando tento a usar apenas para exibir sempre tenho o retorno esperado.

Comando:

```
time ./main
```

Saída:

```
real    0m0.119s
user    0m0.113s
sys     0m0.006s
```

Porém quando tento redirecionar isso para um arquivo com o pipe como o exemplo abaixo, o arquivo permanece em branco e a saída é impressa na tela.

Comando:

```
time ./main >> teste.txt
```

Alguém sabe o que pode estar errado e/ou como eu obtenho o resultado esperado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acordo com o [manual do `time`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/time)

> The  time  command  runs  the  specified program command with the given arguments.  When command finishes, time writes a message to **standard error** giving timing statistics about this program run.

(grifo meu)

Ou seja, o `time` não manda a saída para o `stdout`, e sim para o `stderr`, portanto o direcionamento tem que ser `2>>`:

```
{ time /.main; } 2>> teste.txt
```

ou com subshell:

```
( time ./main ) 2>> teste.txt
```

Notar os colchetes e/ou parênteses, para redirecionar a saída do `time` e não a do `main`. No primeiro caso, estamos agrupando a execução em um codeblock (por isso o `;` no final do comando). No segundo, estamos chamando um subshell, para fazer o agrupamento (neste caso é um desperdício de recursos).

Comment: A resposta levantou outra dúvida, shell é sinônimo de subshell?

Comment: @pmargreff é uma nova instância de shell executada por uma shell. É a mesma coisa, só inventaram um nome diferente por ser uma shell quem fez a chamada da outra.